# Javascript download link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, download, save

Is there any way to create a link that downloads a file without the user having to right-click and choose "save linked file as"? Do you need PHP to do this or can it be executed with Javascript only?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Response Headers that identify a file download are sent by the server, and thus cannot be sent using JavaScript. You'll probably need some server-side lines of code to set the correct headers (like PHP's `header()` function).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example how you can do it with JavaScript but it only works in IE

```
<html>
<head>
<title>xbs_saveas_gt</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function go_saveas() {
    if (!!window.ActiveXObject) {
        document.execCommand("SaveAs");
    } else if (!!window.netscape) {
        var r=document.createRange();
        r.setStartBefore(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]);
        var oscript=r.createContextualFragment('<script id="scriptid" type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://global/content/contentAreaUtils.js"><\/script>');
        document.body.appendChild(oscript);
        r=null;
        try {
            netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
            saveDocument(document);
        } catch (e) {
            //no further notice as user explicitly denied the privilege
        } finally {
            var oscript=document.getElementById("scriptid");    //re-defined
            oscript.parentNode.removeChild(oscript);
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="go_saveas();return false">save the document</a><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Or you can just do `document.print()` and save it as a PDF file

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with php and the header-function, like this:

```
<?php
$fileToOpen = "document.txt"; // the file that you want to download
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$fileToOpen");
header("text/plain"); // Depending on the file
echo file_get_contents($fileToOpen);
```

So your link would point to the php-file instead of the document directly...

Answer (score 0):

Simple PHP:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Location:filenamegoeshere.txt");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
?>
```